# Which is the extent of a service worker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have different apps running on separate folders under the same domain.

```
https://<mydomain>/app1
https://<mydomain>/app2
...
...
```

I have noticed that the service worker running on one folder `(https://<mydomain>/app1)` is extending its operation on the whole domain `https://<mydomain>.`

How can I deploy a service worker for each subfolder without interferences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the scope option in the registration phase.

Basically you would deploy two sw.js files, in both app1 and app2 directories, and restrict them to control only the resources under them.

```
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js', {scope: './'}).then(...)
```

Read more here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/register

Comment: Thank you very much. I missed that option!